# Trouble getting jConnect3 working with Sybase IQ in struts2

Tags: jdbc, struts2, sybase

I am trying to get jconn3.jar driver to connec to Sybase IQ in a struts app.  Here is my config file:

```
<jdbc-driver-params>
<url>jdbc:sybase:Tds://myhost:2641/LDW</url>
<driver-name>com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybDriver</driver-name>
<properties>
 .
 .
 .
```

Unfortunately, this is what the log says:

```
<Creating Connection Pool named jConnectLDW, URL = jdbc:sybase:Tds://myhost:2641/LDW, Properties = user=myUsername;hostname=foo;.>

<registerDriver: driver[className=com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybDriver,com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybDriver@1092d6d2]>

<java.sql.SQLException: JZ003: Incorrect URL format. URL:
at com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.ErrorMessage.raiseError(Unknown Source)
```

I have done quite a bit of hunting and I cannot see a problem with the URL.  Can anyone spot a problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do have the wrong URL in your code.

In the [examples](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc39001.0700/html/prjdbc0700/title.htm) the URL is shown as `jdbc:sybase:Tds:host:port` with examples like `jdbc:sybase:Tds:myserver:3767`

In these cases the host is just the name of the machine and has no path separators (i.e. the \ or /) so try  `jdbc:sybase:Tds:myhost:2641/LDW`

Comment: I think this will fix it.  I still have this issue, but it looks unrelated:  

<java.sql.SQLException: JZ0SJ: Metadata accessor information was not found on this database. Please install the required tables as mentioned in the jConnect documentation.

Thanks for the response.

Comment: yes that is another issue - that is fixed in the server and should be easily found by google